# Dropdown menu not disappearing after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a problem with my top navigation menu. On small screens my menu is opened by clicking the hamburger icon. However, I want the menu to collapse after clicking on one of the items. I hope you guys love to help this newbie. Thank you.

```js
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to topnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#floorplan">Floor Plan</a>
  <a href="#address">Address</a>
  <a href="#projectoverview">Project Overview</a>
  <a href="#locationadvantage">Location Advantage</a>
  <a href="#download">Download</a>
   <a href="#similarprojects">Similar Projects</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

When Im running this code works fine but not disappearing the dropdown. Hope you guys help me.

Comment: Try to figure out why the alert statement is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add to each one of your anchor tags

   `onclick="myFunction()"`
2. To toggle classes on an element use

   ```
   element.classList.toggle()
   ```
3. Use meaningful variable names like myTopNav instead of x.
4. No changes to your CSS.

[MDN classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myTopNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  myTopNav.classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active" onclick="myFunction()">Home</a>
  <a href="#floorplan" onclick="myFunction()">Floor Plan</a>
  <a href="#address" onclick="myFunction()">Address</a>
  <a href="#projectoverview" onclick="myFunction()">Project Overview</a>
  <a href="#locationadvantage" onclick="myFunction()">Location Advantage</a>
  <a href="#download" onclick="myFunction()">Download</a>
  <a href="#similarprojects" onclick="myFunction()">Similar Projects</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```